# Post visibility option to theme front-end for author to select?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, customization, front-end

Is it possible to present author with an option to select visibility of a post (public, private, password) on theme front-end post adding without messing with Wordpress core?
Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you ...

Here is code TF. Please take a look:

```
<?php

if(is_user_logged_in()){
$post_format = '';
if(isset ($_GET['post']) && is_numeric($_GET['post'])){
    $post_id = $_GET['post'];

            $the_source = '';
            $source_meta = meta::get_meta( $post_id , 'source' );
            if(is_array($source_meta) && sizeof($source_meta) &&    isset($source_meta['post_source']) && trim($source_meta['post_source']) != ''){
                    $the_source = $source_meta['post_source'];

            }

    $post_edit = get_post($post_id);
    //VISIBILITY
    $status = get_post_status($post_edit);

            $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
    switch(get_post_format( $post_id )){
        case 'video':
            $post_format = 'video';
            $action_edit_video = true;
            break;
        case 'audio':
            $post_format = 'audio';
            $action_edit_audio = true;
            break;
        case 'link':
            $post_format = 'link';
            $action_edit_link = true;
            break;
        case 'image':
            $post_format = 'image';
            $action_edit_image = true;

            break;
        default:
            $post_format = 'default';
            $action_edit_text = true;


    }

            if(has_post_thumbnail( $post_id )){
                    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
            }

}
    CosmoUploader::init();
?>
<div class="cosmo-box error medium hidden" id="video_error_msg_box">
    <span class="cosmo-ico"></span>
    <span id="video_error_msg" ></span>
</div>
<div class="cosmo-tabs submit" id="d39">
<?php if(!isset($post_id)) { ?>
    <ul class="tabs-nav">
            <?php if( (options::logic( 'upload' , 'enb_image' ) )  ){       ?>
            <li class="first image tabs-selected"><a href="#pic_upload"><span><?php _e('Image','cosmotheme'); ?></span></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if( options::logic( 'upload' , 'enb_video' ) ){   ?>
    <li class="video <?php if( isset($post_id) && $post_format =='video'){echo 'first tabs-selected'; } ?>"> <a href="#video_upload"><span><?php _e('Video','cosmotheme'); ?></span></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if( options::logic( 'upload' , 'enb_text' ) && !isset($post_id)  ){       ?>
            <li class="text <?php if( isset($post_id) && $post_format =='standard'){echo 'first tabs-selected'; } ?>"> <a href="#text_post"><span><?php _e('Text','cosmotheme'); ?></span></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if( options::logic( 'upload' , 'enb_audio' ) && !isset($post_id)  ){      ?>
            <li class="audio <?php if( isset($post_id) && $post_format =='audio'){echo 'first tabs-selected'; } ?>"> <a href="#audio_post"><span><?php _e('Audio','cosmotheme'); ?></span></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if( options::logic( 'upload' , 'enb_file' ) && !isset($post_id)  ){       ?>
            <li class="attach <?php if( isset($post_id) && $post_format =='link'){echo 'first tabs-selected'; } ?>"> <a href="#file_post"><span><?php _e('File','cosmotheme'); ?></span></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
    <?php if( (options::logic( 'upload' , 'enb_image' ) && !isset($post_id) ) || ( isset($post_id) && $post_format == 'image')  ){  ?>
    <div class="tabs-container" id="pic_upload">
            <h3><?php if( isset($post_id) && $post_format == 'image'){ _e('Edit picture','cosmotheme'); }else{ _e('Add picture','cosmotheme'); } ?></h3>
            <?php CosmoUploader::print_form("Attached images","image",true,true)?>
    <form method="post" action="/post-item?phase=post" id="form_post_image" >
                    <div class="field">
                            <label>
                                    <h4><?php _e('Title','cosmotheme')?></h4>
                                    <input type="text" class="text tipped front_post_input" name="title" id="img_post_title"  value="<?php if(isset($action_edit_image)){echo $post_edit -> post_title; } ?>">
                                    <p class="info"  id="img_post_title_info">
                                            <span class="warning" style="display:none; " id="img_post_title_warning"></span>
                                            <?php _e('Be descriptive or interesting!','cosmotheme'); ?>
                                    </p>

                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                            <h4><?php _e('Text content','cosmotheme')?></h4>
                            <?php
                                    if(class_exists('WP_Editor')){
                                            global $wp_editor;
                                            $media_bar = false; /* set to true to show the media bar */
                                            $settings = array(); /* additional settings, */
                    if(isset($action_edit_image)){
                        echo $wp_editor->editor($post_edit -> post_content, 'image_content', $settings, $media_bar);
                    }else{
                        echo $wp_editor->editor('', 'image_content', $settings, $media_bar);
                    }
                                    }else{
                                            if(isset($action_edit_image)){
                                                    wp_editor($post_edit -> post_content,'image_content');
                                            }else{
                                                    wp_editor('','image_content');
                                            }

                                    }
                            ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                            <label>
                                    <h4><?php _e('Category','cosmotheme')?></h4>
                                    <?php
                                    if(isset($action_edit_image) && is_array($post_categories) && sizeof($post_categories) ){
                                            //$cat = get_category( $post_categories[0] );
                    $args = array(  'orderby'            => 'ID',
                                                                'order'              => 'ASC',
                                                                'hide_empty'         => 0,
                                'selected'           => $post_categories[0],
                                                                'id'                 => 'img_post_cat',
                                                        );
                }else{
                    $args = array(  'orderby'            => 'ID',
                                                                'order'              => 'ASC',
                                                                'hide_empty'         => 0,
                                                                'id'                 => 'img_post_cat',
                                                        );
                }

                                    wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
                                    ?>

                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                            <label>
                                    <h4><?php _e('Tags','cosmotheme'); ?> <span>(<?php _e('recommended','cosmotheme'); ?>)</span></h4>
                                    <input id="photo_tag_input" type="text" class="text tag_input tipped front_post_input" name="tags" value="<?php if(isset($action_edit_image)){ echo post::list_tags($post_id); } ?>" placeholder="tag 1, tag 2, tag 3, tag 4, tag 5" autocomplete="off">
                            </label>
                            <p class="info"  id="photo_tag_input_info"><?php _e('Use comma to separate each tag. E.g. design, wtf, awesome.','cosmotheme'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php if(options::logic( 'blog_post' , 'show_source' )){ ?>
                    <div class="field">
                            <label>
                                    <h4><?php _e('Source','cosmotheme')?></h4>
                                    <input type="text" class="text tipped front_post_input" name="source" id="img_post_source"  value="<?php if(isset($action_edit_image)){ echo $the_source; } ?>">
                            </label>
                            <p class="info" id="image_source_input_info"><?php _e('Example: http://example.com','cosmotheme'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="field">
                            <label class="nsfw">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php if(isset($action_edit_image) && meta::logic( $post_edit , 'settings' , 'safe' )){ echo 'checked'; } ?> name="nsfw" value="1"> <?php _e('This is NSFW (Not Safe For Work)','cosmotheme'); ?>
                            </label>
                    </div>

       <!--VISIBILITY -->
       <div class="field">
                            <label>
                                    <h4><?php _e('Visibility','cosmotheme')?></h4>
       <input id="visibility-radio-public" type="radio" class="radio" <?php if (('publish' === $status) && ! post_password_required($post_id)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>value="public" name="visibility" />
        <label for="visibility-radio-public">Public</label>
        <br />
       <input id="visibility-radio-password" type="radio" class="radio" <?php if (('publish' === $status) && post_password_required($post_id)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>value="password" name="visibility">
        <label for="visibility-radio-password">Password:</label>
        <br />
       <input id="post_password" type="text" value="" name="post_password">
        <br />
       <input id="visibility-radio-private" type="radio" class="radio" <?php if ('private' === $status) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>value="private" name="visibility">
        <label for="visibility-radio-private">Private</label>
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_post_visibility" />
         <!--END -->
                    <input type="hidden" value="image"  name="post_format">
                    <?php if(isset($post_id)) { ?>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>"  name="post_id">
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="field button">
                            <p class="button blue">
                                    <input type="button" id="submit_img_btn"  onclick="add_image_post()" value="<?php if(isset($post_id)){ _e('Update post','cosmotheme'); }else{ _e('Submit post','cosmotheme'); } ?>"/>
                            </p>
                    </div>
            </form>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

And here is the function for post with image:

```
        function add_image_post(){
            $response = array(  'image_error' => '',
                                                    'error_msg' => '',
                                                    'title_error' => '',
                                                    'post_id' => 0,
                                                    'auth_error' => '',
                                                    'success_msg' => ''     );


            $is_valid = true;

            if(!is_user_logged_in()){
                    $is_valid = false;
                    $response['error_msg'] = 'error';
                    $response['auth_error'] = __('You must be logged in to submit a post! ','cosmotheme');
            }
            if(is_user_logged_in() && isset($_POST['post_id'])){
                            $post_edit = get_post($_POST['post_id']);

                            if(get_current_user_id() != $post_edit->post_author){
                                    $is_valid = false;
                                    $response['error_msg'] = __('You are not the author of this post. ','cosmotheme');
                                    $response['title_error'] = __('You are not the author of this post. ','cosmotheme');
                            }
                    }
            if(!isset($_POST['title']) || trim($_POST['title']) == ''){
                    $is_valid = false;
                    $response['error_msg'] = 'Title is required. ';
                    $response['title_error'] = __('Title is required. ','cosmotheme');
            }

                    if(!isset($_POST['attachments']) || !is_array($_POST['attachments']) || !isset($_POST['featured']) || !is_numeric($_POST['featured']))
                      {
                    $is_valid = false;
                    $response['error_msg'] = 'error';
                    $response['image_error'] = __('An image post must have a featured image. ','cosmotheme');
                      }


                    if($is_valid){
                            /*create post*/
                            $post_categories = array(1);
                            if(isset($_POST['category_id'])){
                                    $post_categories = array($_POST['category_id']);
                            }

                            $post_content = '';
                            if(isset($_POST['image_content'])){
                            }

                            if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){
                                            $new_post = self::create_new_post($_POST['title'], $_POST['tags'], $post_categories, $post_content, $_POST['post_id']);  /*add image as content*/
                                    }else{
                                            $new_post = self::create_new_post($_POST['title'],$_POST['tags'],$post_categories,$post_content);  /*add image as content*/
                                    }


                                if(is_numeric($new_post))
                                      {
                                            $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $new_post, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );
                                            foreach ($attachments as $index => $id) {
                                                    $attachment = $index;
                                            }
                                            foreach($_POST['attachments'] as $index=>$imageid)
                                              {
                                                    if($imageid==$_POST['featured'])
                                                      {
                                                            set_post_thumbnail($new_post, $imageid);
                                                            unset($_POST['attachments'][$index]);
                                                      }
                                                     $attachment_post=get_post($imageid);
                                                     $attachment_post->post_parent=$new_post;
                                                     wp_update_post($attachment_post);
                                              }

                                            if(isset($_POST['nsfw'])){
                                                    $settings_meta = array(   "safe"=>  "yes");
                                                    meta::set_meta( $new_post , 'settings' , $settings_meta );
                                            }else{
                                                    $settings_meta = array(   "safe"=>  "yes");
                                                    delete_post_meta($new_post, 'settings', $settings_meta );
                                            }

                                            /*add source meta data*/
                                            if(isset($_POST['source']) && trim($_POST['source']) != ''){
                                              $settings_meta = array(         "post_source"=>  $_POST['source']);
                                              meta::set_meta( $new_post , 'source' , $settings_meta );
                                            }else{
                                                    $settings_meta = array(   "post_source"=>  $_POST['source']);
                                                    delete_post_meta($new_post, 'source', $settings_meta );
                                            }

                                            /*add video url meta data*/
                                            $image_format_meta = array("type" => 'image', 'images'=>$_POST['attachments']);
                                            meta::set_meta( $new_post , 'format' , $image_format_meta );

                                            if(isset($_POST['post_format']) && ($_POST['post_format'] == 'video' || $_POST['post_format'] == 'image' || $_POST['post_format'] == 'audio') ){
                                                    set_post_format( $new_post , $_POST['post_format']);
                                            }

                                            if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){ /*if the post is edited */
                                                    $post_status = options::get_value( 'upload' , 'default_edit_status' );
                                            }else{ /* if the post is just created */
                                                    $post_status = options::get_value( 'general' , 'default_posts_status' );
                                            }
                                            if($post_status == 'publish'){
                                                    /*if post was publihed imediatelly then we will show the prmalink to the user*/

                                                    $response['success_msg'] = sprintf(__('You can check your post %s here%s.','cosmotheme'),'<a href="'.get_permalink($new_post).'">','</a>');

                                            }else{
                                                    $response['success_msg'] = __('Success. Your post is awaiting moderation.','cosmotheme');
                                            }
                                            $response['post_id'] = $new_post;
                                }


                    }
            echo json_encode($response);
            exit;
    }
```

Comment: Check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/58818/12615).

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you want to provide this functionality, put the following:

```
<?php
    if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('publish_posts')) {
        $ID = get_the_ID();
        $status = get_post_status($ID);
?>
        Visibility:
        <form id="update_post_visibility" name="update_post_visibility" method="post" action="/update-post-visibility">
            <input id="visibility-radio-public" type="radio" <?php if (('publish' === $status) && ! post_password_required($ID)) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>value="public" name="visibility" />
            <label for="visibility-radio-public">Public</label>
            <br />
            <input id="visibility-radio-password" type="radio" <?php if (('publish' === $status) && post_password_required($ID)) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>value="password" name="visibility">
            <label for="visibility-radio-password">Password:</label>
            <br />
            <input id="post_password" type="text" value="" name="post_password">
            <br />
            <input id="visibility-radio-private" type="radio" <?php if ('private' === $status) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>value="private" name="visibility">
            <label for="visibility-radio-private">Private</label>
            <br />
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_post_visibility" />
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Update" name="submit" />
        </form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

If you want, for instance, to provide this for single posts only, put the code right after `the_post` in your `single.php` file.

**Note**: You have to be in the Loop to use this.

Then create a (private) page (in your WordPress admin) having `update-post-visibility` as slug (or choose whatever you want, but adjust the `action=` of the above form).
The content of that page is as follows:

```
<?php
    if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
        && ! empty($_POST['action'])
        && 'update_post_visibility' === $_POST['action']
        && isset($_POST['post_id'])
    ) {
        $post = array();
        $post['ID'] = $_POST['post_id'];
        switch ($_POST['visibility']) {
            case 'private':
                $post['post_status'] = 'private';
                break;
            case 'public':
                $post['post_status'] = 'publish';
                $post['post_password'] = '';
                break;
            case 'password':
                $post['post_status'] = 'publish';
                $post['post_password'] = $_POST['post_password'];
                break;
        }
        wp_update_post($post);
    }
?>
```

Comment: TF I tried your code but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: I added code to my question.

Comment: Please explain **how** this is not working. Do you get some PHP error (resulting in a blank page)? Are your visibility settings not saved correctly? Don't you even see the _Visibility form_?

Comment: When I set or update visibility status it is always set to Public.

Comment: You did not replace my variable names entirely. You chose to store the post ID in `$post_id`, and in the first few lines you use this variable. Later, however, you use (my variable) `$ID` which is not defined in your case. Simply replace all instances of `$ID` by `$post_id`, then try again and report back.

Comment: I replaced $ID variable with $post_id. Same result.

Comment: Your form posts to `/post-item?phase=post`. What is that page? Where is the code that handles the `wp_update_post`? See my second code block, for the static page. Then, your above code is A) not complete, and B) what is the second function for? Unfortunately, I don't understand both your code and what you want to do.

Comment: TF I sent you theme by email so you could take a look.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I won't do that. I provided you working code (at least for me). If this is not working in your (pretty complex) theme, for some special case in a special template, I'd suggest you first try this on an easy one. Please take your `single.php` and just put the above first code block **as is** below `<article ...` (that's line 35). Then, in your WP admin, create a page with the title _Update post visibility_ (and thus the slug _update-post-visibility_) and put the second code block inside. Then you should see the visibility form for a single post. If so, try to edit and report back.